# What does "Can the reunion" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I'm seeing the *Prison Break* movie (season 4 episode 22) and I faced with "Can the reunion" phrase but when I search for its meaning, I couldn't find any thing.

[Bagwell is meeting with Sucre after a while]

> Bagwell: You are a sight for sore eyes, my friend.

> Sucre: Can the reunion

and suddenly Bagwell's emotions change which can be a hint that indicates "Can the reunion" should have a bad meaning but what is the exact meaning of this phrase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A "reunion" is a meeting where people are reunited. A typical example of such an organised event is a *school reunion*.

To "can" something is slang and means to stop, or get rid of it. It literally means to put something in the garbage can.

Sucre's comment is in response to Bagwell's remarks about his appearance and calling him "friend". The inferred meaning is that this meeting is no happy reunion and they are not friends. Sucre is not pleased to be reuniting with Bagwell and does not appreciate his overly-familiar comments. He wants him to stop and get to the matter at hand.

Comment: Thank you, I just wasn't able to figure it out because I didn't know "Can" means "to stop" too. This word has so many meanings:/

Comment: The process of canning yields canned goods - preserved food. It is only when the (implied) container is a garbage can, that the whole phrase takes the meaning of "stopping something", "cancelling something" or "firing someone". Otherwise, the phrase means to preserve stuff - like fruit.